# What is this * (dereferencing operator ) doing in enum declaration?

Tags: c, pointers, enums

In code walk-through into some others code I found `*` 
What is this ?

here is the same prototype of that code and it's not giving any error.
Only warning comes with `gcc 4.5.2` But on windows it's not giving warning and compiles properly. I can't provide actual code due to IP of the company but I wanted to know this how and why this is correct?

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef enum e
{
        a,
        b,
        c
}x,*y;

int main()
{
        x t=4;
        printf("x : %d\n",t);
        y m=5;
        printf("*y : %d\n",m);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `y m=5;` is a conversion from integer to pointer without a cast. It's well worth paying attention when you get warned for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is equivalent to :

```
typedef enum e *y;
```

So `y` is an alias of `enum e *`, ie `y m` declares `m` as pointer to `enum e`. The following code works indeed as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

x t = 4;
printf("x : %d\n", t);
y m = &t;
printf("*y : %d\n", *m);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is just a special case of the general pattern `typedef TYPE * NAME`, which simply means that "from this point, `NAME` is an alias for the type "pointer to `TYPE`". Here, `TYPE` can be any valid type declaration.

In general, I'm opposed to `typedef`:ing away the asterisk like this, since it makes code that uses the type very confusing. Pointers in C are very important, and it's often good to know if you have a value or just a pointer to a value, and this practice makes that fact hidden.

Comment: +1 for not typedefing the asterisk away, this is horrible when reading code.

Comment: Unless it's a pointer to an incomplete type, in which case as far as the user is concerned it's a handle, and likely they have no business caring whether the handle is implemented as a pointer or an integer. But this example isn't that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a deference operator (in this usage), it's a pointer to an `enum e`.

The reason you're getting a warning is probably this line:

```
y m=5;
```

You're assigning an integer to a pointer. You need to assign it an address:

```
y m=&t;
```